# Change foreground color of an image in Paint.NET

Tags: images, colors, image-editing, paint.net

Let's say we have this picture:

[image]

As you can see, the background color is #2A3D78. The foreground color is #94AEFF. Ultimately, I'd like to get a picture where the background is unchanged, but the foreground becomes #DDDDDD, and that in a smooth way, so the diagonal shadow is altered as well.

Preferably, I'd like to do this within Paint.NET, but if you know another program that does the trick, that'd be awesome as well.

Comment: Does the simple flood fill (paint bucket icon) not work? Make sure you lower the tolerance down from max, and it should get the diagonals too.

Comment: No, that would leave the picture really pixelated between the diagonal lines of the shadow of the logo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in Paint .NET using the [Advanced Color Replacement](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/13544-advanced-color-replacement/) plugin.

- Unzip the downloaded file and put the DLL into the Effects directory in your Paint .NET installation
- Start Paint .NET and open the image
- Set the primary color to *DDDDDD* (for this example) using the Colors tool window
- Choose the color-picker tool and right-click on an area that has the existing color to replace.

  [image]
- Choose **Effects->Color->Advanced Recoloring...**
- Set **Replacement Type** to *Continous* and change the Threshold / Roughness setting until you are happy. You need to be careful here to prevent it from changing the background color as the two colors do not have a lot of contrast.

  [image]
  [image]

Note that other programs like Photoshop will probably be capable of better results though.

Comment: That did the trick :D Thanx a lot :)

Comment: Excellent plugin. Thank you for enlightening me with this answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

What you really need here is a combination of two things:

1. Photoshop (costly, industry standard for a reason), GIMP (free, kinda lousy), Paint Shop Pro (free trial, usable), or some equivalent editing tool *such as Paint.NET - thanks Scott Chamberlain*;
2. A version of your source image which has the elements of the picture on layers of their own.

Without the first, i.e., with only a simple bitmap editor, you won't be able to change the color of the foreground element without either inducing jagginess (pixelation) or messing up other parts of the image, because you can't work on it in isolation.

Without the second, you still can't really work on the foreground element in isolation, because it's blended into the rest of the picture at its edges. If you have the foreground trident (?) on its own layer, then you can change it as you like, and it'll be composed with the background layers to produce a smooth result.

You really can't do this with a simple bitmap editor; you need something with, at minimum, layers and a hue/saturation editing tool, so that you can just recolor the foreground element instead of trying to flood-fill it.

If you can't get a layered source file to work from, then you can probably use the "select contiguous", "magic wand", &c. tool in your chosen image editor to select just the foreground trident, then copy it to a layer of its own and edit it there. You'll probably have to fiddle with the edges a lot to get rid of the background color that creeps in due to the anti-aliasing, though.

The cross-hatched background poses an additional challenge, in that you're going to have a very hard time "lifting" it off the background with the selection tools, and a harder time still getting it separate from the foreground trident. To be honest, you may be better off recreating the image from scratch; to do so would require some knowledge of paths (i.e., vectors), but you'd be able to produce a much nicer result, and would get the extra benefit of being able to further edit it later on.

Comment: [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) is a layered picture editing tool. It even has read compatibility with `.PSD` files.

Comment: Holy wow, I did not know that; I thought "Paint.NET" was a nickname for the ribbon-UI version of `mspaint` that comes with Windows 7. Thanks for the pointer to something I really should've already known!